# Where should I put a method that loads referencing entities?

Tags: entities, 8

I have done the following more than once in my module now:

```
<?php
$fields = FillPdfFormField::loadMultiple(
  $this->entityQuery->get('fillpdf_form_field')
    ->condition('fillpdf_form', $entity->id())
    ->execute());
```

`fillpdf_form_field.fillpdf_form` is an entity reference field pointing at a `FillPdfForm`. One form can have many fields.

I want to refactor this out into its own helper. My first thought is to do it in a service (because I need to inject `QueryFactory`), but I wasn't sure if there was a more clever place to put it. I also couldn't find a generic "load referenc*ing* entities" method anywhere.

Comment: EntityReference field already has method for this. See \Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList::referencedEntities()

Comment: @IvanJaros Yeah, that will let me load the `FillPdfForm` from the form field but not the other way around because the reference is from child to parent, not parent to child.